# installation & configuation the Apache 2 on OpenSuse 12.1 - a quick walktrough

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, configuration, perl, opensuse

experts, good day.

sorry for being the newbie  - i am pretty new to linux and Apache.

i am pretty new to Linux i tried to installl & configure the Apache 2 on OpenSuse 12.1 - here my quick walktrough

is this correct!? see the page 3 /or 4 of the configuration guide.of the http server..

```
Document Root: "/srv/www/htdocs"
Directory; "/srv/www/htdocs"
Alias: /icons/ "/usr/share/apache2/icons/"
Directory: "/usr/share/apache2/icons"
Script Alias: /cgi-bin/ "/srv/www/cgi-bin/"
Directory: "/srv/www/cgi-bin"
mod_userdir.c: empty here nothing is filled in ;-)
include: /etc/apache2/conf.d/*.conf
include: /etc/apache2/conf.d/apache2-manual?conf
Servername linux-r4qe
E-Mail des Servername: root@linux-r4qe
```

while running the apache-configuring tool i have on page 5/5

```
listening on
all, port 80
Standardhost
in 
SSL deaktiviert
Virtuelle Hosts
linux-r4qe in "/srv/www/htdocs", SSL deaktiviert
```

well my question is - is the apache installed and configured correct!?

hope everything is okay here.

**update:** as you might find this question a bit silly or newbie-like.
here some explanations - i have installed the lamp some months ago - but in a wront path...

```
public $unicodeslugs = '0';
    public $feed_limit = '10';
    public $log_path = '/srv/www/htdocs/basic/logs';
    public $tmp_path = '/srv/www/htdocs/basic/tmp';
    public $lifetime = '15';
    public $session_handler = 'database';
}
```

this caused some troubles - eg. permission.errors

In openSUSE, when we install a LAMP solution, usually we run the server in this folder :

> ~/username/public_html.

Since i have had installed my LAMP in srv/www, those folders belong to root. So i had to change the ownership of those folders like that in terminal :

```
su -
password
your_hostname:/home/the_user_to_give_ownership # chown -R the_user_to_give_ownership:users /srv/www
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say "so far, so good".  Apache appears to be running properly, serving requests out of `/srv/www/htdocs`.  Have you tried browsing to the site, to verify that you can connect?

Is there anything specific about the configuration that you are concerned about?

Comment: Have tried browsing to the site, to verify that i can connect - this is all right! All seems well!

Comment: hello dear Lars 
**update:** as you might find this question a bit silly or newbie-like. see above some explanations - i have installed the lamp some months ago - but in a **wrong path.** Therefore i wanted to make sure that **now** all goes well . and is installed and configured properly... guess that i now am doing so!? - many many greetings and thanks for the help